# Oracle - Extract XML nodes values into a list with semicolon as separators

Tags: xml, plsql, oracle11g

I have a XMLType object with below structure:

```
<Parameter>
    <Values>
        <Value>abc</Value>
        <Value>def</Value>
        <Value>ghi</Value>
    </Values>
</Parameter>
```

I'd like to extract the values as a list with semicolon as separator

Expected output would be : abc;def;ghi

I tried many methods (especially with XMLTable) I foud over internet but could not find one which applies to my specific case.

Any help would be appreciated !

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT LISTAGG(x.value, ';') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ROWNUM) AS list
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS JOIN XMLTABLE(
         '/Parameter/Values/Value'
         PASSING XMLTYPE(t.xml)
         COLUMNS
           value VARCHAR2(3) PATH './text()'
       ) x
```

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( xml ) AS
SELECT '<Parameter>
    <Values>
        <Value>abc</Value>
        <Value>def</Value>
        <Value>ghi</Value>
    </Values>
</Parameter>' FROM DUAL;
```

Which outputs:

> | LIST |
> | --- |
> | abc;def;ghi |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=891cb666843c2b1c4fb5ee7cf50d2535)*

Comment: I could quickly adapt this to my own code, and got the expected result. Many thanks for the quick reply !